# Lattice lines with integer coordinates in 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to draw a surface in a 3D plot together with gridlines (horizontal lines and vertical lines) parallel to x y z axes with integer coordinates. Of course not only on faces, but also inside the box. For example

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[16- x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

with grid lines pass through all integers in plot region.

Comment: And what have you tried? Mathematica is really hard to learn only by reading other people's code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slightly more/different than OP requested, but why not?

```
g = Plot3D[Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
           Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7]]
```

> [image: Sphere]

Next define a function that gets us all the rectangles we need, wraps them into a `Head` of `Polygon` and overlays them onto the original plot:

```
addgrids[g_Graphics3D] :=
 Module[{ranges = {Floor@#1, Ceiling@#2} & @@@ PlotRange@g, rects},
  rects =
   Function[{perm},
     Map[Function[{points}, Prepend[points, #]],
        Tuples[Rest@#][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] &@perm] & /@ 
      Range @@ First@perm] /@
    (RotateRight[ranges, #] & /@ Range[3]);
  rects =
   MapIndexed[Function[{list, amount},
     Map[RotateLeft[#, First@amount] &, list, {2}]], rects];
  Show[{g,
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], Polygon@Flatten[rects, 1]}]
    }]
  ]
```

Then simply post-process the plot with this function:

```
g // addgrids
```

> [image: with grids]

While I'm at it, here's a similar approach for adding grid-*lines*, rather than grid-surfaces:

```
addlines[g_Graphics3D] := 
 Module[{ranges = {Floor@#1, Ceiling@#2} & @@@ PlotRange@g, lines},
  lines =
   Function[{perm},
     Flatten[
      Block[{i, j, Table = Table}, ClearAttributes[Table, HoldAll];
       (Table[{{First@First@perm, i, j}, {Last@First@perm, i, j}},
           {i, Sequence @@ #1}, {j, Sequence @@ #2}] & @@ (Rest@
           perm))], 1]] /@
    (RotateRight[ranges, #] & /@ Range[3]);
  lines =
   MapIndexed[Function[{list, amount},
     Map[RotateLeft[#, First@amount] &, list, {2}]], lines];
  Show[{g,
    Graphics3D[Line@Flatten[lines, 1]]
    }]
  ]

g // addlines
```

[image: gridlines]

Answer (score 5):

Just something to get you started:

```
rng = {{0, 5.8}, {0, 6.9}};
pts = Tuples[Range @@@ IntegerPart@rng];
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], Evaluate[Join[{x}, First@rng]], Evaluate[Join[{y}, Last@rng]]],
 Graphics3D[(Line@{Append[#, 0], Append[#, f @@ ##]} & /@ pts)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something as simple as the [`FaceGrids`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html) option will work for you.

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotTheme -> "ZMesh",
  PlotRange -> All,
  FaceGrids -> All]
```

[image: plot3d]

Comment: I edited my question. maybe it is now more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could Use the Show function to join a Graphics object containing your lines to you Graph:

```
lines = {{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}, {{-2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}, {{-2, 
 1, -.5}, {2, 1, -.5}}, {{-2, 1, .5}, {2, 1, .5}}, {{1, -2, 
 0}, {1, 2, 0}}};

Show[Plot3D[{Sin[x + y^2]/2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]], Graphics3D[{Red, Line[lines]}]]
```

[image: Lines in a simple Sine plot]